# Create too many classes or have some schema-less data structure(like dictionary)?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm have to use 50 different custom datatypes(/classes) which are defined in a document(xml/json), they have only fields and no methods and maybe strong validations.
My question is should i go ahead and create(/generate) 50 classes or use some generic data structure (like HashMap<String,Object>)?

Update: My fear is if i go with class geneartion, then my codebase might increased by very much 
and if go with schema-less way, my data integrity might be compromised, so which one is lesser evil.

Comment: You could use JAXB to bind XML to objects.

Comment: My problem is not parsing, its just that i'm going to use these different classes multiple times and i don't want them to be too generic. FYI some of the fields may have an default value

Comment: "Don't want them to be too generic" - I didn't say anything about parsing being a problem.  I'm suggesting that you let JAXB generate those classes for you by annotating XML.  If you don't want generic, you shouldn't go with that Map idea.

Comment: What is "too generic"??  JSON can be very easily/naturally translated to Maps/Lists, and that's a reasonable representation for the situation you describe.  If you're careful to use meaningful variable names and structure your code well it's a very good way to deal with an "arbitrary" data layout.

Answer (score 2):

Unless it is just ridiculous, more code is more forgivable, in general.  There are a few different reasons:

If you give them base classes at the right points, you can have it both ways, as your handling code can hold the base classes, and may have anchor points for extracting, validating or cleaning information stored in the different formats.  Surely some of the processing can be shared.

If absolutely everything really falls to the base class, you can refactor the sub-classes out of existence without pain.  On the other hand, if you start the amorphous way, gathering the special cases back into separate classes is more likely to go wrong.

Excessively large code is only bad if the extra volume does not clarify the logic for readers.  I would have the classes, if they constitute units in which people think.

Also, actual functionality is more important than format or even readability.  So if the risk is to data integrity vs code bloat, protect the content, not the form.